# Customize Sign Up Pop-up from auth0

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, auth0

I am trying to customise the auth0 Sign Up tab. I am trying to redirect the user when clicking on the Sign-up button to my own website to make the payment.
The following code is in app.js file and it's not working. Where can I find the default code from auth0, or do I need to create another instance of the Auth0Lock as I did?

```js
    var lock = new Auth0Lock(
        'ClientId',
        'AppDomain',
        {
            auth: {
                redirect: 'components/template/template.html'
            }
        }
    );

    lock.on("authenticated", function (authResult) {
        lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function (error, profile) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("error");
            }

            localStorage.setItem('token', authResult.idToken);
            localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Auth0 Lock option [`redirect`](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#redirect-boolean-) is a boolean value to flag which mode to use (redirect/popup). It's not intended for what you're trying to achieve.

There is also a [`redirectUrl`](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#redirecturl-string-) option, but that is for the URL Auth0 will redirect to after authentication is completed.

If you want to require users to provide additional information when signing-up for your application you could do so through Lock support for [custom fields](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/custom-signup#using-lock), however, it seems that you need much more control on the process so the recommended approach is to let the user do the normal signup procedure and then use [redirect rules](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/custom-signup#redirect-rules).

> One way to use social IDP signups with Lock and collect custom fields is to **use redirect rules to redirect the user to another page (Ideally, a webtask or a custom page hosted by you) where you ask for extra information, and then redirect back to finish the authentication transaction**.

(emphasis is mine)

For detailed information about using redirect rules see: [Redirect Users from Rules](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/redirect)